# Получить список из JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Здравствуйте. Есть класс RateObject:

```
public class RateObject {

private String name;
private double rate;

public RateObject(String name, double rate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rate = rate;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getRate() {
    return rate;
}}
```

Есть GET запрос, получает JSON-строку:

```
http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=RUB&symbols=USD
```

Есть десериализатор:

```
public class RatesDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<RateObject> {
@Nullable
public RateObject deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                              JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    RateObject rate = null;
    if (json.isJsonObject()) {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries =
                json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
        if (entries.size() > 0) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = entries.iterator().next();
            rate = new RateObject(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getAsDouble());
        }
    }
    return rate;
}
```

}
Эта строка создает объект на основе JSON объекта:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(RateObject.class, new RatesDeserializer())
                .create();
```

Все работает хорошо, но как мне получить объект из запроса:

```
http://api.fixer.io/latest?callback=?
```

Точнее, интересует список валют и их коэффициент. Сейчас, просто меняя запрос, мы получаем только первую строку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что следует поменять?

Comment: Если Вам нужно получить список коэффициентов для всех валют, то запрос должен быть несколько другой: `http://api.fixer.io/latest` (здесь base-валюта по-умолчанию -- EUR) или `http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD` (здесь base-валюта указана явно). В данный момент пара `валюта-коэффициент` у Вас представляет собой объект `RateObject`, но для хранения нескольких пар целесообразно в классе, в котором хранится объект класса `RateObject` заменить его на `HashMap<String, Double>`, в таком случае скорее всего не нужен будет кастомный десериализатор.

Comment: Все понял, спасибо большое!) Поздравляю тоже с прохождением первого этапа)

Answer (score 1):

У JSON-документов в этом случае простая структура, как по мне, вам следует поменять также маппинг, не особо заморачиваясь с преобразованием через кастомный десериализатор. Так, например, такой маппинг подходит для всех типов запросов, указанных как в самом вопросе, так и в комментариях к нему:

```java
final class RateObjectDto {

    final String base = null;
    final Date date = null;
    final Map<String, Double> rates = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("RateObject{")
                .append("base='").append(base).append('\'')
                .append(", date=").append(date)
                .append(", rates=").append(rates)
                .append('}').toString();
    }

}
```

Обратите внимание на `Map<String, Double> rates`, а не `HashMap<String, Double> rates` -- Gson использует упорядоченный вариант `Map` по-умолчанию (свой собственный `LinkedTreeMap`), что гарантирует проход по `rates` в том порядке, в котором поле `rates` пришло от сервиса. Судя по десериализатору и изначальном маппинге, нужно взять только одно значение и можно просто добавить в сам маппинг пару методов, которые этим и займутся. (Конечно, в DTO не должно быть логики как таковой (за исключением разве что некоторых преобразований), но ввиду простоты и краткости здесь этим правилом можно принебречь.)

```java
boolean isSingle()
        throws IllegalStateException {
    switch ( rates.size() ) {
    case 0:
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    case 1:
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

double getSingle()
        throws IllegalStateException {
    if ( !isSingle() ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    return rates.values().iterator().next();
}
```

После этого уже у самого `RateObjectDto` можно спросить, является ли он семантическим эквивалентом оригинального маппинга:

```java
private static final String JSON_1 = "{\"base\":\"RUB\",\"date\":\"2017-02-24\",\"rates\":{\"USD\":0.01721}}";
private static final String JSON_2 = "{\"base\":\"EUR\",\"date\":\"2017-02-24\",\"rates\":{\"AUD\":1.3816,\"BGN\":1.9558,\"BRL\":3.277,\"CAD\":1.3907,\"CHF\":1.0649,\"CNY\":7.2873,\"CZK\":27.021,\"DKK\":7.4344,\"GBP\":0.84503,\"HKD\":8.2341,\"HRK\":7.4275,\"HUF\":308.59,\"IDR\":14128.0,\"ILS\":3.9241,\"INR\":70.664,\"JPY\":119.04,\"KRW\":1198.2,\"MXN\":20.893,\"MYR\":4.7109,\"NOK\":8.8365,\"NZD\":1.4711,\"PHP\":53.255,\"PLN\":4.3107,\"RON\":4.517,\"RUB\":61.644,\"SEK\":9.5188,\"SGD\":1.4892,\"THB\":37.006,\"TRY\":3.7991,\"USD\":1.0609,\"ZAR\":13.702}}";
private static final String JSON_3 = "{\"base\":\"USD\",\"date\":\"2017-02-24\",\"rates\":{\"AUD\":1.3023,\"BGN\":1.8435,\"BRL\":3.0889,\"CAD\":1.3109,\"CHF\":1.0038,\"CNY\":6.869,\"CZK\":25.47,\"DKK\":7.0076,\"GBP\":0.79652,\"HKD\":7.7614,\"HRK\":7.0011,\"HUF\":290.88,\"IDR\":13317.0,\"ILS\":3.6988,\"INR\":66.608,\"JPY\":112.21,\"KRW\":1129.4,\"MXN\":19.694,\"MYR\":4.4405,\"NOK\":8.3292,\"NZD\":1.3867,\"PHP\":50.198,\"PLN\":4.0632,\"RON\":4.2577,\"RUB\":58.105,\"SEK\":8.9724,\"SGD\":1.4037,\"THB\":34.882,\"TRY\":3.581,\"ZAR\":12.915,\"EUR\":0.9426}}";

private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

public static void main(final String... args) {
    parseAndDump(JSON_1);
    parseAndDump(JSON_2);
    parseAndDump(JSON_3);
}

private static void parseAndDump(final String json) {
    final RateObjectDto rate = gson.fromJson(json, RateObjectDto.class);
    System.out.println(rate);
    if ( rate.isSingle() ) {
        System.out.println(rate.getSingle());
    }
}
```

Результат таков:

> RateObject{base='RUB', date=Fri Feb 24 00:00:00 EET 2017, rates={USD=0.01721}}
>
> 0.01721
>
> RateObject{base='EUR', date=Fri Feb 24 00:00:00 EET 2017, rates={AUD=1.3816, BGN=1.9558, BRL=3.277, CAD=1.3907, CHF=1.0649, CNY=7.2873, CZK=27.021, DKK=7.4344, GBP=0.84503, HKD=8.2341, HRK=7.4275, HUF=308.59, IDR=14128.0, ILS=3.9241, INR=70.664, JPY=119.04, KRW=1198.2, MXN=20.893, MYR=4.7109, NOK=8.8365, NZD=1.4711, PHP=53.255, PLN=4.3107, RON=4.517, RUB=61.644, SEK=9.5188, SGD=1.4892, THB=37.006, TRY=3.7991, USD=1.0609, ZAR=13.702}}
>
> RateObject{base='USD', date=Fri Feb 24 00:00:00 EET 2017, rates={AUD=1.3023, BGN=1.8435, BRL=3.0889, CAD=1.3109, CHF=1.0038, CNY=6.869, CZK=25.47, DKK=7.0076, GBP=0.79652, HKD=7.7614, HRK=7.0011, HUF=290.88, IDR=13317.0, ILS=3.6988, INR=66.608, JPY=112.21, KRW=1129.4, MXN=19.694, MYR=4.4405, NOK=8.3292, NZD=1.3867, PHP=50.198, PLN=4.0632, RON=4.2577, RUB=58.105, SEK=8.9724, SGD=1.4037, THB=34.882, TRY=3.581, ZAR=12.915, EUR=0.9426}}

Кстати, `http://api.fixer.io/latest?callback=?` нельзя разобрать средствами Gson напрямую, если не пользоваться довольно низкоуровневыми ухищрениями с ручным парсингом входного потока и отдать Gson-у только часть этого входного потока: наличие аргумента для параметра `callback` возвращает данные в формате [JSONP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).